# Can you deserialize a struct from a map or a string?

Tags: rust, serde, serde-json

Consider this `Config` struct which contains a vector of `Host` structs:

```rust
use serde::Deserialize;
use std::net::IpAddr;

#[derive(Debug, Deserialize)]
struct Config {
    name: String,
    hosts: Vec<Host>
}

#[derive(Debug, Deserialize)]
struct Host {
    addr: IpAddr,
    user: String,
}
```

Using the derived `Deserialize` implementation, the following JSON and YAML config files can be deserialized successfully with `serde_json` and `serde_yaml`:

```json
{
  "name": "example",
  "hosts": [
    { "addr": "1.1.1.1", "user": "alice" },
    { "addr": "2.2.2.2", "user": "bob" }
  ]
}
```

```yaml
---
name: example
hosts:
  - addr: 1.1.1.1
    user: alice
  - addr: 2.2.2.2
    user: bob
```

However, I would like to also be able to deserialize the `Host` struct from a string. But, it's important that I can also deserialize it from a map, and ideally the vector could be composed of both formats. For example:

```json
{
  "name": "example",
  "hosts": [
    "alice@1.1.1.1",
    { "addr": "2.2.2.2", "user": "bob" }
  ]
}
```

```yaml
---
name: example
hosts:
  - alice@1.1.1.1
  - addr: 2.2.2.2
    user: bob
```

With `#[serde(try_from = "String")]` on top of the `Host` struct, I can easily support the string deserialization... but then it doesn't deserialize the map format anymore.

The serde website has a [page](https://serde.rs/string-or-struct.html) about deserializing either a string or a struct, but it requires the `deserialize_with` attribute which can only be applied to a field (not to a struct container). I'm not sure this technique would work as my field is a `Vec<Host>` and not just a `Host`.

Is this possible to achieve?

Comment: I think that's you need to implement a manually deserialize, see https://serde.rs/deserialize-struct.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use an untagged enum for that. Combined with a custom deserializer:

```rust
use std::str::FromStr;
use serde::{Deserialize, Deserializer};
use std::net::IpAddr;

#[derive(Debug, Deserialize)]
struct Config {
    name: String,
    hosts: Vec<Host>,
}

#[derive(Debug, Deserialize)]
struct InnerHost {
    addr: IpAddr,
    user: String,
}

#[derive(Debug, Deserialize)]
#[serde(untagged)]
enum Host {
    #[serde(deserialize_with = "deserialize_host_from_str")]
    FromStr(InnerHost),
    FromDict(InnerHost),
}

fn deserialize_host_from_str<'de, D>(deserializer: D) -> Result<InnerHost, D::Error>
where
    D: Deserializer<'de>,
{
    let value = String::deserialize(deserializer)?;
    // parse the value and return host
    Ok(InnerHost {
        addr: IpAddr::from_str("1.1.1.1").unwrap(),
        user: "foobar".to_string(),
    })
}

fn main() {
    let data = r#"{
  "name": "example",
  "hosts": [
    "alice@1.1.1.1",
    { "addr": "2.2.2.2", "user": "bob" }
  ]
}"#;

    let config : Config = serde_json::from_str(data).unwrap();
    println!("{:?}", config);
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=9dd5e351de472bdf36266c13b4782d8d)

For convenience you can add an `AsRef` impl of for `Host` to `InnerHost` or a method to extract it from the enum.

Comment: Or you can use [`serde (from="HostEnum")`](https://serde.rs/container-attrs.html#from) to extract the host automatically from the enum ([playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=cc5b79ddd98e882b9256b1300b81a49e))

Comment: @Jmb, nice add! Thanks!

Comment: Great solution! Thank you both :)

Answer (score 1):

Here is an even cleaner solution that does not need to expose a wrapper type. Modified from [here](https://github.com/QuarticCat/misc/blob/main/rust/serde_shorthand.rs).

```rust
use serde::{Deserialize, Deserializer};
use std::net::IpAddr;
use std::str::FromStr;

#[derive(Debug, Deserialize)]
struct Config {
    name: String,
    hosts: Vec<Host>,
}

#[derive(Debug)]
struct Host {
    addr: IpAddr,
    user: String,
}

impl<'de> Deserialize<'de> for Host {
    fn deserialize<D: Deserializer<'de>>(deserializer: D) -> Result<Self, D::Error> {
        #[derive(Deserialize)]
        #[serde(remote = "Host")] // cannot use `Self` here
        struct This {
            addr: IpAddr,
            user: String,
        }

        #[derive(Deserialize)]
        #[serde(untagged)]
        enum Helper {
            Short(String),
            #[serde(with = "This")]
            Full(Host),
        }

        Ok(match Helper::deserialize(deserializer)? {
            Helper::Short(value) => {
                let _ = value; // parse value here
                Self {
                    addr: IpAddr::from_str("1.1.1.1").unwrap(),
                    user: "foobar".to_string(),
                }
            }
            Helper::Full(this) => this,
        })
    }
}

fn main() {
    let data = r#"{
      "name": "example",
      "hosts": [
        "alice@1.1.1.1",
        { "addr": "2.2.2.2", "user": "bob" }
      ]
    }"#;

    let config: Config = serde_json::from_str(data).unwrap();
    println!("{:?}", config);
}
```

[Rust Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=43204143dd6d0573abeb9e2cd10a7df8)

All deserialization logic is done within the `Host` type itself without any convention for its caller (I mean `Config` type here).

The key idea is using `remote` attribute to let the default deserialize function be generated in another namespace.